# Better way of parsing string to boolean

Tags: c#, sharepoint

At the moment I am using this to check a boolean property in sharepoint 2007 using C# and .Net Framework 3.5

```
if (bool.Parse(listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"].ToString()) == false)
```

is there any better way of doing it ?

**Edit**

when my code try to convert property into string it gives me exception even when am validating if property is empty or not.

**This Worked For me**

using method "Contains Key" instead of "Properties.Containsfield"

```
object abc = "bool property";

foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
{
     if (item.Properties.ContainsKey(abc)
```

Comment: I explained some of the errors that your approach is likely to generate in my answer.  My guess is it's either a `NullReferenceException` or a `FormatException`

Comment: Unrelated, but note that use of boolean literals in comparisons is something that I’d flag in every code review. Boolean literals have one use, and one use only: to initialise a boolean value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am making some assumptions about your code, specifically that `listItem` is of type [`SPListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415089.aspx) and that [`listItem.Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem_properties.aspx) is a [`HashTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aahzb21x).  This is mainly to provide context for my explanation, but even if I am mistaken, most of my comments will still hold.  For the sake of context, let's assume your actual method looks like:

```
 void HandleBooleanListItemProperty( SPListItem listItem ){ 
    if (bool.Parse(listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"].ToString()) == false){ 
        // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
    } 
    else
    { 
        // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
    }
}
```

1. Validate that the object exists before you call `ToString()`.  The way your method is currently written, you will get a `NullReferenceException` if the key "Boolean Property" is missing or the hashed value that corresponds to the "Boolean Property" key is `null`.  This refactoring will make the method look like:

   ```
   void HandleBooleanListItemProperty2( SPListItem listItem ){ 
        object booleanPropertyValue = listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"];
        if ( ReferenceEquals( booleanPropertyValue, null ) ) {
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is missing
        } 
        else if (bool.Parse(booleanPropertyValue.ToString()) == false){ 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
        } 
        else { 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
        }
    }
   ```
2. Use `bool.TryParse` instead of `bool.Parse`.  If the `ToString()` value of the hashed value corresponding to the key "Boolean Property" is anything other than "true" or "false" (case-insensitive), a `FormatException` will be thrown.  This refactoring will make the method look like:

   ```
    void HandleBooleanListItemProperty3( SPListItem listItem ){ 
        object booleanPropertyValue = listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"];
        bool parsedBooleanPropertyValue;
        if ( ReferenceEquals( booleanPropertyValue, null ) ) { 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is missing
        }
        else if (bool.TryParse(booleanPropertyValue.ToString(), out parsedBooleanPropertyValue) ) 
        {
            if(parsedBooleanPropertyValue == false){ 
               // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
            }
            else { 
              // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
            }
        } 
        else { 
             // do something if the Boolean ListItem property's ToString() value was something other than "true" or "false"
        }
    }
   ```
3. If the hashed value that corresponds to the "Boolean Property" key is really a `bool`, then cast it before comparing.  Calling `ToString()` just throws away .NET's type-safety.  This refactoring will make the method look like:

   ```
    void HandleBooleanListItemProperty4( SPListItem listItem ){ 
        object booleanPropertyValue = listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"];
        if (booleanPropertyValue is bool) 
        {
           bool castBooleanPropertyValue = (bool) booleanPropertyValue;
            if( castBooleanPropertyValue == false ){ 
               // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
            }
            else { 
              // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
            }
        } 
        else { 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is not a bool        
            if ( ReferenceEquals( booleanPropertyValue, null ) ) { 
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is missing
            }
            else {
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is something other than a bool
            }
        }
    }
   ```
4. Eliminate magic strings from your value accessor.  This requires removing the inline `"Boolean Property"` and declaring with that value, and then using the constant in order to access the value in every usage.  This decreases the possibility that a typos will cause bugs.  An article on magic strings is available at: http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2009/03/19/functional-net-lose-the-magic-strings/ .  The resulting refactoring would look like:

   ```
    const string BooleanPropertyKey = "Boolean Property";

    void HandleBooleanListItemProperty5( SPListItem listItem ){ 
        object booleanPropertyValue = listItem.Properties[BooleanPropertyKey];
        if (booleanPropertyValue is bool) 
        {
           bool castBooleanPropertyValue = (bool) booleanPropertyValue;
            if( castBooleanPropertyValue == false ){ 
               // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
            }
            else { 
              // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
            }
        } 
        else { 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is not a bool        
            if ( ReferenceEquals( booleanPropertyValue, null ) ) { 
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is missing
            }
            else {
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is something other than a bool
            }
        }
    }
   ```
5. Use the negation operator (`!`) instead of comparing to false.  This is much more readable and will save you time in the long run.  This final refactoring looks like:

   ```
    const string BooleanPropertyKey = "Boolean Property";

    void HandleBooleanListItemProperty6( SPListItem listItem ){ 
        object booleanPropertyValue = listItem.Properties[BooleanPropertyKey];
        if (booleanPropertyValue is bool) 
        {
           bool castBooleanPropertyValue = (bool) booleanPropertyValue;
            if( !castBooleanPropertyValue ){ 
               // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is false
            }
            else { 
              // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is true
            }
        } 
        else { 
            // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is not a bool        
            if ( ReferenceEquals( booleanPropertyValue, null ) ) { 
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is missing
            }
            else {
                // do something if the Boolean ListItem property is something other than a bool
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: thanks for explaining it in details and I did tried number 5, but when property is there it isn't going to first if statement but going to else statement and I just debugged and looked at what property is returned as and its returned as "1" for that particular item and code thinks its not boolean

Comment: @TimeToThine, I guess you are used to working with JavaScript, huh?  In C#, `1` is not a `Boolean`.  It is an integer.  You can use the same approach with `int` instead of `bool`, and then check `if( ((int)listItem.Properties[BooleanPropertyKey]) == 1 )`

Comment: sorry am bit confused now, I looked at XML returned by SharePoint in my solution while its attached to list and in XML it got "1" as value for that property but when I tried to get values of all items using console app, its giving me as true, however for one item I am getting "object not set to reference" for which I think has been already added before custom property wasn't added to list.

Comment: XML stores a boolean value as a `1`.  This is different than the C# literal `1`.  If you are deserializing the XML document to a `HashTable`, it should be converted to a `Boolean`.  Your problem is that there is no value in the `HashTable` with the key "Boolean Property", so when you ask the `HashTable` for it, it gives you `null`.  When you ask `null` for `ToString()`, it gives you a `NullReferenceException` ("Object not set to a reference")

Comment: thats true, I think I want to catch this this null exception in a way that I can do something with it without throwing any exception, just like you explained it in code above, but number 5 isn't working like it should be :(

Comment: @TimeToThine, I guarantee you the code will "work like it should".  Maybe you are not realizing that a null reference will not be seen as a `bool`.  So, for example, if there is no "Boolean Property" attribute in the XML element, then there will be no reference in the `HashTable`, and so it will throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

The `.Parse` methods will throw exceptions if the value is null, in a bad format, etc.

I suggest always using the `.TryParse` methods instead:

```
bool val;
if(!bool.TryParse(listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"].ToString(), out foo)) {
    val = false;
}
```

Or perhaps one of the [`Convert.ToBoolean()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) methods.